# Automated GUI testing framework for Android

Tags: android

Does there exist an automated GUI testing framework for Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is support baked right into the SDK. Check out the [Activity Testing](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html) topic on the Android dev site.

Comment: The correct link is now http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html

Comment: Thanks Rémi, I updated my post with the new link.

Answer (score 9):

There is also a [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out android native driver for white box testing and robotium, fonemonkey for blackbox testing.

Answer (score 0):

some state-of-the-art testing tools working with android

[Windriver Fast](http://www.windriver.com/announces/fast/)

[TestPlant](http://www.testplant.com/)