# Android testing framework for non-developers

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251066/automated-gui-testing-framework-for-android). I am looking for automated test frameworks for Android where test cases can be written by **technical QA people**.

All the frameworks ive seen so far require thorough knowledge of Java, JUnit, Eclipse, Adb, Activities, etc.

Comment: Why use people when you can [let monkeys do it](http://d.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html)! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out TestDroid at http://bitbar.com/.

It has an eclipse plugin that lets you simply press record (like a macro) and it will generate the test code (using Robotium) for you.